# Plotting the result of R table with multiple columns

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe d with 5 columns (col1-col5) of type "logical". I wanted to get counts for all combinations of True and False across the 5 columns so I used

`dt = table( cd$ol1, d$col2, d$col3, d$col4, d$col5 )`

This give me the answer I wanted with a count for each combination of True and False across rows:

```
> dt
, ,  = FALSE,  = FALSE,  = FALSE

       
         FALSE   TRUE
  FALSE    133    466
  TRUE       0      0

, ,  = TRUE,  = FALSE,  = FALSE

       
         FALSE   TRUE
  FALSE      7    675
  TRUE       0     62

, ,  = FALSE,  = TRUE,  = FALSE

       
         FALSE   TRUE
  FALSE     28    157
  TRUE       0     26

, ,  = TRUE,  = TRUE,  = FALSE

       
         FALSE   TRUE
  FALSE      0   3398
  TRUE       0   1596

, ,  = FALSE,  = FALSE,  = TRUE

       
         FALSE   TRUE
  FALSE     60     39
  TRUE       0      0

, ,  = TRUE,  = FALSE,  = TRUE

       
         FALSE   TRUE
  FALSE      6     16
  TRUE       0      4

, ,  = FALSE,  = TRUE,  = TRUE

       
         FALSE   TRUE
  FALSE     80   2063
  TRUE      10   1079

, ,  = TRUE,  = TRUE,  = TRUE

       
         FALSE   TRUE
  FALSE      5 124601
```

I would now like to plot the results. I realised you can just do

```
> plot(dt)
```

and this seems to do the right thing but it is not a very nice plot.
Can someone recommend a better way of plotting the output of table with multiple columns?

Edit:
changed "data.table" to "table" - that was a stray find/replace, sorry about that.
Providing example data frame:

```
d <- data.frame( id=c(1:10),col1=c(T,T,F,F,T,T,F,T,F,T),col2=c(F,T,T,F,F,T,F,T,F,T),col3=c(F,F,T,F,T,T,F,F,F,T),col4=c(T,T,F,F,T,F,T,T,F,T),col5=c(T,F,F,T,T,T,F,T,T,F) )
```

so I am looking for recommendations for good visualisations of the result of counting the combinations of True/False that you get from

```
table( d$col1, d$col2, d$col3, d$col4, d$col5)
```

the data I get from the table operation is exactly what I need and I'm sure there is a way of plotting this but I am not sure what type of plot would work well here. Thanks!

Comment: can you show us your dataset?

Comment: It looks like you should substitute all occurrences of "data.table" with "table" in your questions (and its title and tags).

Comment: oops, sorry, stray find/replace there... yes, it is "table" not "data.table" everywhere. Edited now.
The actual data is too long to post here but I will add a toy example in a minute. NOt much to see though, just one column of IDs and 5 columns of logical data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe `library(vcd)` will be useful?

```r
d <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1:10),
    col1 = c(T, T, F, F, T, T, F, T, F, T),
    col2 = c(F, T, T, F, F, T, F, T, F, T),
    col3 = c(F, F, T, F, T, T, F, F, F, T),
    col4 = c(T, T, F, F, T, F, T, T, F, T),
    col5 = c(T, F, F, T, T, T, F, T, T, F)
  )


library(vcd)
mosaic(col1 ~ col2|col3, data = d)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking how to plot multidimensional data. You could use ggplot2 with `geom_bin_2d`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d,
       aes(x = col1, y = col2)) +
  geom_bin_2d() +
  facet_grid(interaction(col3, col4) ~ col5,
             labeller = function(...) label_both(..., sep = "\n"))
```

[image: resulting plot]

However, just two more dimensions and the only option I see is a mosaic plot.

Comment: thank you Roland, nice solution. I prefer the vcd solution but this is also a good one, thanks!